# undefined method `capture' for RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to write a spec to test displaying a tic-tac-toe board. I am using the method `capture` but it throws an error when I run the spec. I am using capture to get the output of a method call. https://apidock.com/rails/Kernel/capture
Here is my method:

```
  def display_board
    puts " #{grid[0]} | #{grid[1]} | #{grid[2]} "
    puts "-----------"
    puts " #{grid[3]} | #{grid[4]} | #{grid[5]} "
    puts "-----------"
    puts " #{grid[6]} | #{grid[7]} | #{grid[8]} "
  end
```

Here is my Rspec test:

```
context "#display_board" do
     output = capture(:stdout) { board.display_board}
     rows = output.split("\n")
     binding.pry
     expect(rows[0]).to eq("   |   |   ")
     expect(rows[1]).to eq("-----------")
     expect(rows[2]).to eq("   |   |   ")
     expect(rows[3]).to eq("-----------")
     expect(rows[4]).to eq("   |   |   ")
  end
```

Comment: What's the error, specifically?

Comment: ```NoMethodError:
  undefined method `capture' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Board::DisplayBoard:Class```

Comment: `#capture` was a method that *used to* be available from ActiveSupport, but it looks like it was deprecated and removed. So this approach isn't going to work.

Comment: Is there any method you recommend?

Comment: Yeah I'll write up an answer with some possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `#capture` was deprecated and removed.

Personally, I would separate I/O from the generation of the game content, because it's easier to work with and test that way. So instead of `puts`, just build up a string containing your board (with a `\n` at the end of each line) and test that for correctness. In the actual game, output the board to the console with one `puts` call.

If you really want to capture STDOUT, there is a way. `$stdout` is a global containing a reference to the current STDOUT stream. By default this is always set to `STDOUT`, a constant representing the actual STDOUT of the program, but you can redirect `$stdout` to another IO stream, for example a `StringIO` object. `puts` will write to whatever `$stdout` refers to instead of directly writing to `STDOUT` (there is a subtle difference there!).

```
$stdout = StringIO.new
puts 'this is my output'
captured_output = $stdout.string
$stdout = STDOUT # restore it when you're done
```

Now you have 'this is my output' (followed by a newline character) captured in `captured_output`. But you'll also have anything else that went to STDOUT in that time, so it's not ideal (e.g. console output in your ruby console). You should wrap that in a method that ensures it's always restored, e.g.

```
def capture() 
  $stdout = StringIO.new
  yield
  $stdout.string
ensure
  $stdout = STDOUT
end
```

You can use this with a block, e.g.

```
capture { puts 'xyz' } 
=> 'xyz\n'
```

(But you'll have an easier life if you forget this approach and just build your board up as a string.)

Answer (score 1):

`capture` was removed from Rails, but I liked it and brought it back, mostly for use in my spec suites.  I extracted the exact Rails code, along with the complete test suite, and then improved the test suite.  The gem is called `silent_stream`, it works with Rails 5, 6, and partially with rails 7. You can find it here: https://github.com/pboling/silent_stream

This is how you use it for output capturing:

```
# Make the methods avaialble:
RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include SilentStream
end

# Then add an expectation on output:
it 'has output' do
  output = capture(:stdout) { subject.request(:get, '/success') }
  logs = [
      'INFO -- request: GET https://api.example.com/success',
      'INFO -- response: Status 200'
  ]
  expect(output).to include(*logs)
end
```

## An Even Better Solution

Recent versions of RSpec have an output matcher built-in!  Use this instead.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:output